# Linear arrangement of 4 eagles, 3 horses and 5 dragons in which no two dragons get placed side by side

Tags: combinatorics

I want to check my answer because I am not sure the answer key is correct.

> Consider there are 12 creatures: 4 eagles, 3 horses and 5 dragons. They need to be placed in a row in which no two dragons get placed side by side. How many arrangements are there? Note that each creature must be considered as a distinct object.

My attempt:

The eagles and horses must be placed first as depicted as numbers below.

__ 1 __ 2 __ 3 __ 4 __ 5 __ 6 __ 7 __

A line represents a seat for a dragon.

There are $7!$ ways to place eagles and horses and $\frac{8!}{(8-5)!}=\frac{8!}{3!}$ ways to place dragons. So there are
$$
\tfrac{4}{3}(7!)^2
$$
ways to arrange those creatures in which no 2 dragons get placed side by side.

Is it my combinatorial argumentation correct?

Comment: The answer key is $(7!)^2/2$ that seems to be incorrect.

Comment: Why must the Korean and Japanese students be placed first? The Chinese students could also, for example, occupy seats 1, 4, 6, 8, and 10.

Comment: @AndrewChin Thinking the Korean and Japanese students are the first citizens makes the combinatorial argumentation much simpler. In your example, the configuration is the same as _(c1)_ 1 __  2 _(c2)_  3 _(c3)_ 4 _(c4)_ 5 _(c5)_ 6 __ 7 __

Comment: I changed the objects to avoid any possible issue related to ethnics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is perfect, and couldn't have done better.The answer key is wrong

Comment: OK. I am waiting for other answers (if any). I am not sure.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer Your answer is correct.

Comment: @LawNgai: Thanks.